# Filtering with DoubleMetaphoneFilter in Lucene

Tags: filter, lucene

I want to use DoubleMetaphone in Lucene programmatically.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-phonetic</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The above package contains appropriate classes.

This filter can be used in Solr via setting xml.

But I want it to use in Java programmaticaly.

```
analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);
String field = "title";
Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_44, field, analyzer).parse(querystr);
int hitsPerPage = 100;
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
searcher.search(q, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

But I don't know how I use the filter.

Answer (score 0):

To use this filter, you'll need to create your own custom Analyzer, similar to the example in the [Analyzer documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html).  If you want to add a metaphone filter to

```java
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        final StandardTokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_44, reader);
        source.setMaxTokenLength(StandardAnalyzer.DEFAULT_MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH);
        TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, filter);
        filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, filter);
        filter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, filter, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
        filter = new DoubleMetaphoneFilter(filter, 4, true);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter)
    }
}
```

That is just an example, of course.  Setup you Analyzer however makes sense for the data you want to index.

Also, keep in mind that this filter will need to be applied at index time, as well as query time, so you will need to reindex your data with this filter applied to index the metaphone codes.